# What is the use of event_prefix and cache_tag variable magento 2 model file

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.2, magento2.4

When I am looking into magneto model files I find

```
<?php
namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Model;
class Post extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel implements \Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface
{
    const CACHE_TAG = 'mageplaza_helloworld_post';

    protected $_cacheTag = 'mageplaza_helloworld_post';

    protected $_eventPrefix = 'mageplaza_helloworld_post';

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Model\ResourceModel\Post');
    }

    public function getIdentities()
    {
        return [self::CACHE_TAG . '_' . $this->getId()];
    }

    public function getDefaultValues()
    {
        $values = [];

        return $values;
    }
}
```

Here what is the use of `const CACHE_TAG, $_cacheTag, $_eventPrefix`?

When we can use these variables.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**$_eventPrefix**

Prefix of model events names, this prefix will be used in *beforeLoad* and *afterLoad*, *beforeSave*, *afterSave*, *afterCommitCallback* and another relative event dispatcher.

See this generic abstract class for more information on how it is being used. `<root>/vendor/magento/framework/Model/AbstractModel.php`

**CACHE_TAG and $_cacheTag**

- Both are the same if you take a deep look at `AbstractModel.php`.
- Model cache tag for clearing cache after saving and after deleting.
- Used to distinguish the cache type from all other cache. Sort of identities to each object, in this case, it is a blog post etc.